# "1 others reacted with thanks" is grammatically incorrect

Tags: bug, grammatical-correction, reactions

So I have just tried the ***thank*** feature only to see this somehow feels weird to me.
As a non-native English speaker, I am not sure if it is correct or not at this part with **s**.

[image: thank]

Shouldn't "others" have no **s** or even better -- "1 person"?

Comment: The advantage of "other[s]" is that you can just prepend "You and " and it still makes sense

Comment: You're correct that it shouldn't have the 's' for only one: "1 other" but "2 others" for anything above 1. The way Nick has written it: "1 other[s]" or "2 other[s]" would be a potential fix for this.

Comment: or... we could just remove the tooltip

Comment: @BSMP my argument was more against the use of person, that's in no way better, the pluralisation bug should absolutely be fixed though so it becomes *"You and 1 other..."* and *"You and 2 others..."*

Comment: @KevinB Why stop at just the tooltip?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery because, this question is about the tooltip.

Comment: @Nick "*you can just prepend "You and " and it still makes sense *" that's OK but I'd really prefer it *at least* it was "people" rather than "others". I'm OK with "1 people reacted with **thanks**" - whatever. What I find really annoying is that on *my* posts, it still says "others". It can never say "You and" because I cannot thank myself. Similarly if I never click the thanks reaction on a post, it's always going to say "X others". Any time I see that I have to ask my self "other than?"

Comment: @VLAZ *"What I find really annoying is that on my posts, it still says "others".  It can never say "You and" because I cannot thank myself"* - That is a very valid criticism and would make a good addition to your question

Comment: @Nick it's not *my* question.

Comment: @VLAZ Well..... guess I need coffee then

Comment: @Nick and 1 others :D

Comment: Don't mention Jeff Atwood.